# NotFoundError: No registered 'PyFunc' OpKernel for 'CPU' devices compatible with node {{node PyFunc}} . Registered: <no registered kernels>

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am getting an error while trying to access data from a tf.data.Dataset object.
The dataset object is built from a generator. Any help will be appreciated.
I'm using TensorFlow 2 and trying to run the example from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator

```
def gen(): 
  for i in itertools.count(1): 
    yield (i, [1] * i) 

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( 
     gen, 
     (tf.int64, tf.int64), 
     (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None]))) 

list(dataset.take(3).as_numpy_iterator())
```

The  error is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    662         # Fast path for the case `self._structure` is not a nested structure.
--> 663         return self._element_spec._from_compatible_tensor_list(ret)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    664       except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_from_compatible_tensor_list'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py in execution_mode(mode)
   1896     ctx.executor = executor_new
-> 1897     yield
   1898   finally:



...  
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ac0e933e02b3> in <module>
----> 1 list(dataset.take(3).as_numpy_iterator())

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __next__(self)
   3640 
   3641   def __next__(self):
-> 3642     return self.next()
   3643 
   3644 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in next(self)
   3637 
   3638   def next(self):
-> 3639     return nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.numpy(), next(self._iterator))
   3640 
   3641   def __next__(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in __next__(self)
    628 
    629   def __next__(self):  # For Python 3 compatibility
--> 630     return self.next()
    631 
    632   def _next_internal(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in next(self)
    672     """Returns a nested structure of `Tensor`s containing the next element."""
    673     try:
--> 674       return self._next_internal()
    675     except errors.OutOfRangeError:
    676       raise StopIteration

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    663         return self._element_spec._from_compatible_tensor_list(ret)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    664       except AttributeError:
--> 665         return structure.from_compatible_tensor_list(self._element_spec, ret)
    666 
    667   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     97                 value = type()
     98             try:
---> 99                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    100             except StopIteration as exc:
    101                 # Suppress StopIteration *unless* it's the same exception that

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py in execution_mode(mode)
   1898   finally:
   1899     ctx.executor = executor_old
-> 1900     executor_new.wait()
   1901 
   1902 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/executor.py in wait(self)
     65   def wait(self):
     66     """Waits for ops dispatched in this executor to finish."""
---> 67     pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_ExecutorWaitForAllPendingNodes(self._handle)
     68 
     69   def clear_error(self):

NotFoundError: No registered 'PyFunc' OpKernel for 'CPU' devices compatible with node {{node PyFunc}}
    .  Registered:  <no registered kernels>
```

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you using? It's possible your version doesn't match that of the docs. It's also possible that the TF2 docs aren't entirely up to date.

Comment: I'm using TF2. Finally I understand why it's not working. I firstly have to emphasize that the code is running on CPU and GPU without error. I only have this error when I run it on TPU. According to my searches the TPU server is unable to run python code then I have to rewrite the generator using operations available in the tensorflow api.

Comment: The example I posted is a very simple case. Sometimes the instructions in the generator can be very complex and require calling some external api written in python. I wonder if tensorflow provide a solution where the generator's code is not runed from the TUP server but is executed on the client machine and the outputs streamed to TPU server.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to execute your code in TF 2.2.0 in Google colab

For the benefit of community, here i am posting the successful run with output

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import itertools

def gen(): 
  for i in itertools.count(1): 
    yield (i, [1] * i) 

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( 
     gen, 
     (tf.int64, tf.int64), 
     (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None]))) 

list(dataset.take(3).as_numpy_iterator())
```

Output:

```
2.2.0
[(1, array([1])), (2, array([1, 1])), (3, array([1, 1, 1]))]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for sharing. Is your code working with TPU?

Comment: Yes, I changed hardware accelerator to `TPU` in Google Colab and ran the above code, it's working.

Comment: I am getting the same exception with this code as well on Google Colab with TF 2.0

Comment: I am also getting the same error with this code on google colab with TPU for tf 2.2. Are you sure you enabled TPU?

Comment: p.s. just switching to the TPU accelerator doesn't utilize the TPU. You actually need some boiler plate code to initialize the model on the TPU. https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tpu.ipynb

Comment: I think The problem is the itertools module and python's yield instruction. TensorFlow cannot run python code on the TPU server, what it does is that it convert all python instruction in a graph before it can run it. So if your function contains some instruction that TensorFlow cannot parse or some call to external modules, the execution will fail on TPU

Comment: for this reason, I think tf.data.Dataset.from_generator cannot work on TPU